# Eclipse shortcut to select or remove all spaces up to (but excluding) the next word

Tags: eclipse, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

For years I was working with Netbeans and the following is one of the very few features that I cannot find in eclipse:

How can I select or remove all trailing or preceding spaces up to (but excluding) the next or previous word respectively, in one keystroke combination.

In netbeans <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> would just do this.

Comment: Would [Eclipse 20199.12/4.14](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58344908/6309) help?

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse,

```
Shift+Ctrl+Left   =  Select previous word

Shift+Ctrl+Right  =  Select next word
```

---

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> = To jump to end or start of a word.

Then pressing
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> **twice** selection will select **white spaces** between two words.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. I still get the spaces and the next word selected. I only need to select the white space.

Comment: Which editor you are using Java editor C/C++ editor or text editor?

Comment: Java editor, but same happens on html, xml, json, md, plain file editors. Strangely it does NOT happen on js editor (in forword selection only).