# Select everything inside spaces keyboard shortcut

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any keyboard shortcut to select everything separated by space?

For example:
`<img className="header__logo" src={logo} alt="Logo" />`

And I want to click anywhere inside classname press shortcut and it selects `classname="header__logo"`, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your code editor. [In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002163/eclipse-shortcut-to-select-or-remove-all-spaces-up-to-but-excluding-the-next-w), for example, works in eclipse but not in a few other editors.

In VSCode I often use CTRL + SHIFT + [LEFT OR RIGHT ARROW] to select words quickly.

Comment: Yep, I use it as well, but the problem is, if I start from the middle, I will not be able to select everything.